# Calling Thread that returns when complete

Tags: c#, multithreading

I need to call a separate thread from winform app and waiting for it as long as its work is complete without lock UI, for instance:

```
// ButtonClick event handler
Thread t = new Thread(OnThread);
t.Start();
MessageBox.Show("Complete");

voin OnThread()
{
    // some long running work here..
}
```

So the messagebox should appears when OnThread function returns.
Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a number of applicable solutions to this problem. The solution that you choose will depend on the semantic meaning of your code and the target framework version.

The most applicable solution given our conversation, would be to raise an event once the `OnMethod` method has completed and then code your continuation within the event handler like this

```
private void buttonSomething_Click(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    OnMethodCompleted += (s, e) =>
    {
        MessageBox.Show("...");
    };
    Thread thread = new Thread(OnMethod);
    thread.Start();
}

private void OnMethod()
{
    // Some long running operation here..
    OnMethodCompleted(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}

private static event EventHandler OnMethodCompleted = delegate { };
```

Comment: Messagebox is an example only..I really would be able to exectue a different thread and wait for it. I'm using .NET 4.0 Are there other solutuons?

Comment: @bit You can use make use of the TPL and accompanying `Task` class then. Updated my answer.

Comment: Is it possibile without using Task class?

Comment: You could use a `BackgroundWorker`? Here is a basic [tutorial](http://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker).

Comment: No. I want use thread class. I'm very curiously how can I wait for separate thread return without freeze UI, just as Task class already does.

Comment: @bit Okay. This is not at all ideal but you could raise an event from the `OnThread` when the method operation has completed.

Comment: Sure, I can raise some event but cthe code inside button will continue its own execution even whether thread is not complete and I don't want this behavior..

Comment: @bit You would bring that code out into the event handler. Hold on, let me show you.

Comment: Ok, I' ve accepted your answer, however I thought there was some .NET class able to wait thread execution. In reality, the only way is some workaorund just as you did show me. Ok, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You could play with Delegates.

```
var threadStart = new ThreadStart(OnThread);
threadStart+= OnThreadEnds;//<--Combine multicast delegate
Thread t = new Thread(threadStart);
t.Start();

void OnThread()
{
    // some long running work here..
}

voin OnThreadEnds()
{
    // Here pass the control to UI thread and show message box
    //MessageBox.Show("Complete");
}
```